# C++ - Use friend keywords to improve efficiency?

Tags: c++, performance, friend

For example, i have this two class (from an exercise of C++ Primer):

```
class Message{
   set<Folder> folders;
public:
   void addFolder(Folder f);
}

class Folder{
   set<Message> messages;
public:
   void addMessage(Message m);
}
```

The method addFolder (equal to addMessage), is something like this:

```
void addFolder(Folder f){
    folders.push_back(f);
    f.addMessage(this);
}

void addMessage(Message m){
    messages.push_back(m);
    m.addFolder(this);
}
```

The problem is that this way i will have an infinite recursive call to this two method (the folder add the message, than the message add the folder and ask the folder to add the message etc..).

I have two solution in mind:

1.Have a public member in each class that return a bool, this value indicate if a given message/folder is in the set of the object:

```
void addFolder(Folder f){
    folders.push_back(f);
    if(!f.search(this)){
       f.addMessage(this);
    }
}

void addMessage(Message m){
    messages.push_back(m);
    if(!m.search(this)){
        m.addFolder(this);
    }
}
```

This should work, but every time i have to control the set two times.

The other solution is to have a private member in each class that only add the folder/message without asking the other to add it. Then make this to class friends.

```
class Message{
   friend class Folder;
   set<Folder> folders;
public:
   void  addFolder(Folder f);
private:
   void insertFolder(Folder f){ folders.push_back(f);}
}

class Folder{
   friend class Message;
   set<Message> messages;
public:
   void addMessage(Message m);
private:
   void insertMessage(Message m){ messages.push_back(m);}
}
```

The addMessage and addFolder method will be:

```
void addFolder(Folder f){
    folders.push_back(f);
    f.insertMessage(this);
}

void addMessage(Message m){
    messages.push_back(m);
    m.insertFolder(this);
}
```

This way there will not be recursive call, and it will be more performant.

In situations like this, it's fine to use friend to improve efficiency? Or it's better to use a less performant way (like the search way?) and not to use the friend keyword?

Comment: I would consider changing the whole design

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot wrong with your design. You are recursing as messages have folders and folders have messages. You need to compare folders and messages and you have no concept of ownership.

You need to forget code for a moment and look at data modelling.

You have a group of folders. I will assume each one has a folder id.
You have a group of messages. Each one has a message id.

You have a many-to-many relationship between folders and messages.

Given a message id you should be able to see all the folders it is contained in.
Given a folder id you should be able to see all the messages it contains.

I am assuming that "folders have messages" but actually it is just a many-to-many relationship. You could use two multimaps to store the relationship.

```
std::multimap< FolderId, MessageId >;
std::multimap< MessageId, FolderId >;
```

You would also want regular maps

```
std::map< FolderId, Folder >;
std::map< MessageId, Message >;
```

In place of `Folder` or `Message` in the last two maps you could use a smart-pointer type that enables placement and retrieval. I'd go simple and use `shared_ptr`.

Instead of the multimaps, you could also just contain a set in each Folder / Message object. This would simply be a map from Id to Id. You'd then refer to the "manager", i.e. the main maps to retrieve the underlying object.

So we could have

```
class Message
{
   std::set< FolderId > folderIds; // folders I am in

  // implement construction and access functions etc.
};

typedef std::shared_ptr< Message > MessagePtr;

class Folder
{
   std::set< MessageId > messageIds; // messages in this folder
};

typedef std::shared_ptr< Folder > FolderPtr;
```

Put the big maps into some kind of manager

```
class MessageFolderManager
{
    std::map< FolderId, FolderPtr > folders
    std::map< MessageId, MessagePtr > messages;
};
```

Note that for dependencies, Folder and Message probably only need to know about the Ids of the other type, not the other type itself. So in Folder.h you'd only include the header definition for the MessageId, and vice versa. Thus you won't get a dependency issue. The manager needs to include all the class types.

Comment: +1 well described.  Using `std::vector<Folder>` / `std::vector<Message` with the id being the `vector` index is another simpler/faster option if they're never erased until the whole Message/Folder data is done with.

Comment: Yes, that is true if you never remove any.

And if the manager "owns" all the objects then you don't need to use shared_ptr, you just retrieve the reference. 

If you are going to remove items, it is much easier to do with containers of sets. e.g. you go to the message object you are removing to get the ids of all the folders it is in. You then go to each folder to "erase" that message.

multimap is bad for removing items by value.

Comment: I did not understand how you add messages and folders with this implementation :/ Can you help me?

Comment: Assuming the above model (using shared_ptr) you would create a Message with new, put it into a shared_ptr, and have a method in MessageFolderManager to add it to the map given its id. Your MessageFolderManager may even manage the ids, i.e. assign you one.

You'd then have methods to associate it with folders. If you want to create a Message / FolderId relationship you'd find the appropriate Folder object for its id, add the MessageId tot that folder's set, and add the folder's id to your message's set. The manager could have a method to do all that for you.